# How can I use pthreads to read from many running processes at once?

Tags: c, file-io, pthreads

I'm using pthreads in a "work crew" pattern where I have a large number of commands to run, and I want to read the output from each command and merge all the outputs.  Using pthreads I create one worker thread per core, and each worker thread essentially does the following:

```
for (;;) {
   const char *command = get_from_work_queue();
   if (command == NULL)
       break;
   FILE *fp = popen("long-running-command", "r");
   // ... loops reading fp until EOF
   // enqueue data read from fp
}
```

Both `get_from_work_queue` and "enqueue data" require the thread to temporarily acquire a mutex, as the queues are shared, but these mutexes are released before any call to `popen()` or `fread()`.

My issue is that although I have four cores and four worker threads, only one long-running command is going at any one time.  The other three threads are just sitting around, probably waiting to be scheduled.

I assume that something about `popen` or `fread` is blocking *all* the threads, and not just the caller.  How can I read from a command *without* blocking other threads, so I can have four long-running commands going at the same time?

Comment: Why not use `select` with a bunch of file descriptors?

Comment: The accepted answer here: [popen() alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743771/popen-alternative) may be worth a try to see if you get better/desired behavior.

Comment: @PhilBrubaker I can't quite see why forking an extra shell would make a difference---and the truth is I *need* to run the shell.  But it could be worth a try.

Comment: @EdHeal coding with select(2) is a huge pain in the ass.  I was really hoping for threads with non-blocking I/O.  But I may be SOL.

Comment: A [simple test](https://gist.github.com/keaston/ac6dfbdb0d494ab31d67755aeef01dfa) shows that having multiple `popen()` commands running simultaneously from multiple threads works fine.  If you backtrace your threads in gdb, where are they stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it works fine if I use `read(2)` instead of `fread(3)`.  For slightly more detail see my answer to [What multithreading package for Lua "just works" as shipped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689548/what-multithreading-package-for-lua-just-works-as-shipped/42929964#42929964)